# Does $\int _{\mathbb{R}^d}f\circ\phi \,\, d\mu =\int _{\mathbb{R}^d}f\circ\psi \,\, d\mu $ imply $\phi=\psi$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be Borel Probability measure, and $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\psi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable mappings defined $\mu$-almost everywhere.

My claim is that if
$$\int _{\mathbb{R}^d}f\circ\phi \,\, d\mu =\int _{\mathbb{R}^d}f\circ\psi \,\, d\mu $$
for every bounded Borel function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we have $\phi=\psi\,\,\,\text{$\mu$-almost everywhere}.$

Is it true?

Obviously $f\circ\phi=f\circ\psi$ for positive $f$ but I can't go further.

Comment: If you rewrite this in terms of the pushforward measures and note that it holds for continuous functions doesn't this imply the result?

Comment: @3-in-441 But it does not hold for continuous functions.

Comment: @Did Sorry, why?

Comment: Because every $\psi(x)=\phi(x+z)$ solves this. Or because of the answer below. Or simply because it does not...

Answer (score 1):

Since a bounded Borel function is a uniform limit of a sequence of linear combinations of Borel sets, the problem reduces to the following one:

> Let $\mu$ be Borel Probability measure, and $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\psi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable mappings defined $\mu$-almost everywhere. If $\mu\left(\phi^{-1}(B)\right)=\mu\left(\psi^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)  $ for any Borel subset $B$, then $\phi=\psi$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

But we can assume that $d=1$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval. We consider $\phi\colon x\mapsto x$ and $\psi\colon x\mapsto 1-x$ for example.

The key expression here is "measure preserving mapping".